# Consuming data from windows share through java code in linux

Tags: java, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

This is little vague in nature but that is because I have to start working on this.

We are planning to use Windows Share Drive. We will be automatically picking these files from windows share (from java code running at Linux) and using them for further processing.

1. Is there any known issue in using windows share from java code from Linux? How do we do this? Is mounting the file system only way?
2. Can we run various file system commands to list files (or move/lock/delete a file etc.)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Aapche commons-vfs.  It has support for SMB (Windows Shares). http://commons.apache.org/vfs/

Specifically - http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#CIFS

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks helpful! From what I understand, it shouldn't be any issue anymore. Similarly, any good link for setting up filewatcher which can keep an eye on windows share and informs us on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jcifs](http://jcifs.samba.org/) to deal with samba in my project. There is a class named `jcifs.smb.SmbFile` similar to `java.io.File` can handle samba file like local file. Methods like  `listFiles()`, `delete()`, `exists()`, `getInputStream()`,`createNewFile()` should meet your needs.

Here is a downland file demo, hope it helps you.

```
    SmbFileInputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    //
    String souFileUrl = "smb://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + server + "/" + souFileName;

    SmbFile souSmbFile = new SmbFile(souFileUrl);
    is = new SmbFileInputStream(souSmbFile);
    File tempOutFile = new java.io.File(newfilename);
    os = new FileOutputStream(tempOutFile);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int c;
    while ((c = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, c);
    }
```